# Solving convex separable programming problem using interior point method?

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-programming, simplex, approximation-algorithms, interior-point-method

In my engineering application, all decision variables are non-negative and everything is convex separable. In addition to that, the only function that I am trying to approximate with grid point are $f(x)=x^3$ and $g(y)=y^4$.

I am having this strange feeling about solving separable programming problem. Particularly for imposing the following requirement on the $\lambda$.

1. At most 2 $\lambda$ are positive
2. They must be adjacent

[image]

From what I know, this can be done by modifying the entering and leaving variable of the simplex tableu. However, if I am using an interior point method solver like MOSEK then how can I impose these constraint ?